# Installing Python 3.1.2 from source, how do you resolve the sqlite3-dev dependency?

Tags: python, sqlite, makefile, gnu, ubuntu-9.04

Running ubuntu 9.04 "jaunty".

When I run make I get the following error:

```
Python build finished, but the necessary bits to build these modules were not found:
_sqlite3
```

So the easy solution is to just install the missing dependency using apt-get, "sudo apt-get -f install libsqlite3-dev" but I get the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libsqlite3-dev: Depends: libsqlite3-0 (= 3.6.10-1) but 3.6.10-1ubuntu0.2 is to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

I tried uninstalling "libsqlite3-0" but synaptic said many things needed it (50+).

So now I am stuck. I can't install the missing dependency. And therefore I can not install python 3.1.2.

**Any ideas on how to fix the missing libsqlite3-dev dependency?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dependency mismatch in that error message doesn't agree with the official [ubuntu repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/jaunty-updates/libsqlite3-dev).  (The official version of libsqlite3-dev in Jaunty depends on `libsqlite3-0  (= 3.6.10-1ubuntu0.2)`.)  Perhaps your last `apt-get update` was done while the repo was still being updated and only *some* of the latest packages were available.

Try again after running `sudo apt-get update`, perhaps first switching to a different apt server.  (You can do this in the Ubuntu GUI using the Software Sources system administration tool.)

Or, if you don't want to mess with building and installing Python manually, you could upgrade Ubuntu to the latest release.  Lucid has Python 3.1.2 in the repositories already, as python3.